# Hurwitz theorem (complex analysis) and real functions?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

A corollary to [Hurwitz' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) from complex analysis states the following:

> **Corollary (Hurwitz).** Suppose $f_N:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $f_N\neq 0$ on $\Omega$, and $f_N\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Then either $f\equiv 0$ or $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

I was wondering if there was a similar or related theorem for a real-valued sequence of functions $g_N:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ ?

After some thought I could see that the corollary cannot be used for real-valued functions due to the holomorphic condition, but wondered if there were any analogous theorems from real analysis?

Comment: If $f$ is real analytic on a connected open set :-).

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for your comment. Are you saying that if $f(x,y)$ is real analytic on a connected open set and $f_n(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $n$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly then $f\equiv 0$ or $f\neq 0$ ? Do you have a link or reference where I could learn more...

Comment: Well, basically it can be extended to a holomorphic function on some set containing the interval in question so it would follow from the above result (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1034715/27978, for example).

Comment: Ah I see, yes I had entertained that thought, thanks.