# Euler-Gauss Limit Formula for the Complex Gamma Function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

Suppose we have the function $\Gamma$ defined for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathrm{Re}~ z > 0$ by the standard integral formula
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{z - 1} dt$$
(perhaps extended to $\mathbb{C}$ except $0,-1,-2,\ldots$ via recurrent relation), and that we aim to prove the identity
$$\Gamma(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^z n!}{z (z+1) \ldots (z + n)}.$$
In the real case, there is a relatively simple proof of this identity utilising log-convexity of $\Gamma$ (demonstrated, e.g., in Artin's *Gamma Function*).

Is there any simple way how to use the identity for real-variable $\Gamma$ (or the log-convexity argument) to obtain the identity in the complex case? It is trivial if one knows that both sides of the identity are analytic functions – but this seems to me as relatively non-trivial compared to the rest of the stuff.

My main motivation for asking this question is that I have found multiple sources, which effectively state the proof for $\Gamma$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and then claim that they have proved the property for $\Gamma$ over $\mathbb{C}$. I am therefore curious if there is some simple argument that can be used in the transtion from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034701/do-real-analytic-functions-always-extend-uniquely-to-complex-analytic-functions) adequately address your question?

Comment: @EricTowers Not really, I think. If I understand that answer correctly, this is just what I mention in the penultimate paragraph: if you know that both sides are analytic functions, the task is easy...

Comment: Since the logarithm behaves differently on the complex plane I feel you should end needing analyticity anyway but just my intuition so not sure